# How to solve Ruby Wizardry "Staying in the loop" example program?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, while-loop

The book Ruby Wizardry Chapter 4 includes the following sample program

```rb
we_wanna_ride = true
stops = ["East Bumpspark", "Endertromb Avenue", "New Mixico", "Mal Abochny"]

while we_wanna_ride
    print "Where ya headin', friend?"
    destination = gets.chomp
    if stops.include? destination
    puts "I know how to get to #{destination}! Here's the station list:"
        stops.each do |stop|
            puts stop
            break if stop == destination
        end
    else
        puts "Sorry, we don't stop at that station. Maybe another time!"
        we_wanna_ride = false
    end
end
```

It then goes on to pose a few additional challenges:

"What if a passenger is going the other way on the train (for instance, from Mal Abochny to East Bumpspark)? How could you update your program to work in both directions? Even trickier, what if the train route is a big circle (meaning if a passenger goes from East Bumpspark to Mal Abochny, the next stop after Mal Abochny should be East Bumpspark again)? How could you update your program to print out the right list of train stops if a passenger wants to go all the way around the circle?"

Does anybody have any ideas how to proceed here ? I'm a beginning programmer so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my progress so far. I figured I would get a `departure` from the user and then use to.i to get the input into an integer. I could then use the integer value to compare to the index position in the array. If the rider wants to go in the opposite direction I could use something like stops.each.reverse to print out the array items in reverse order.

```rb
we_wanna_ride = true
stops = ["East Bumpspark(1)", "Endertromb Avenue(2)", "New Mixico(3)", "Mal Abochny(4)"]
puts "#{stops}"

while we_wanna_ride
    print "Select a destination number"
    destination = gets.chomp.to_i
    print "Select a departure number"
    departure = gets.chomp.to_i
    if departure <= destination
        stops.each do |stop|
            puts stop
            break if stop == destination
        end
    else puts "Sorry"
    we_wanna_ride = false
    end
end
```

Comment: It's usually easier to get an answer if you post an attempt you made rather than a completely open-ended problem. Try it out and edit your question to include your attempt, what you expected to work, and what happened instead.

Comment: Thanks @Max ! I hope my new description is more useful. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this challenge.  It works but is rather lengthy.  More advanced ruby coders may be able to provide a shorter solution:

```
    we_wanna_ride = true
stops = ["East Bumpspark", "Endertromb Avenue", "New Mixico", "Mal Abochny"]

while we_wanna_ride
  print "Where do you wish to depart from?: "
  depart = gets.chomp.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  depart_index = stops.index(depart)
#  puts depart_index

  print "Where ya headin' friend?: "
  destination = gets.chomp.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  destination_index = stops.index(destination)
#  puts destination_index

  index_diff1 = depart_index - destination_index
  index_diff2 = destination_index - depart_index

  if stops.include? destination && depart
    puts "\nI know how to get to #{destination}! Here's the station list:"

    if destination_index > depart_index && index_diff2 < 3
      stops[depart_index..-1].each do |stop|
        puts stop
        break if stop == destination
      end
    we_wanna_ride = false

    elsif destination_index > depart_index && index_diff2 >= 3
      dubstops = stops.concat(stops)
      dubstops[0..depart_index+4].reverse_each do |stop|
        puts stop
        break if stop == destination
      end
    we_wanna_ride = false

    elsif destination_index < depart_index && index_diff1 < 3
      stops[0..depart_index].reverse_each do |stop|
        puts stop
        break if stop == destination
      end
    we_wanna_ride = false

    elsif destination_index < depart_index && index_diff1 >= 3
      dubstops = stops.concat(stops)
      dubstops[depart_index..-1].each do |stop|
        puts stop
        break if stop == destination
      end
    we_wanna_ride = false
    end

  else
    puts "Sorry, we don't service that station. Maybe another time!"
    we_wanna_ride = false
  end
end
```